# RandomForest no calculation of OOB error

Tags: r, random-forest

I am a newbie in the field of Random Forest models and trying to interpret the outputs of several RF models. The datasets used are fairly large (approx 5,000 rows and more, five predictor variables, all numeric) and while the models (using R packages randomForest and RandomForestSRC for comparison and better plotting) seem to run fine and I'm getting %var explained around 40%, for some reason I seem unable to compute the OOB error. It should appear together wiht the confusion matrix in the RF summary but all I get is e.g. this:

[image]

The code I am currently running using randomForest package is:

```
rf3 <-randomForest(fishing_hours ~ . , data = data_fish, ntree = 1000, importance=TRUE, do.trace=100)
```

Trying to access OOB error rates using `rf3$err.rate[,1]`, I am getting NULL as results or NAs are listed and plotting rf3 looks like this:

[image]

I am doing a regression - any chance to obtain error rates or advice on other useful model performance indicators?

Any help much appreciated - happy to share a sample dataset if needed.

Comment: I tried the model$err.rate[,1] as suggested in answers to that question and it gives me NULL. Will clarify that in my question

Comment: @divibisan Thank you very much, I had not seen that. Indeed I am doing a regression. Any idea how to get error rates or any other model performance indicator in this case? RandomForestSRC gives me an error rate but I haven't found how to interpret it yet.

Comment: @divibisan OK, I was looking at that but was hoping for more I guess. Thank you very much. Do you want to answer the question properly so I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `random.forest` package only calculates OOB error (`err.rate`) and a `confusion` matrix when you're doing classification.

Mean squared error is what is normally used to determine error rate for Regression problems and you can access that from `models$mse`.

This answer on CrossValidated might also be helpful:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305046/best-way-to-evaluate-a-random-forest-model-accuracy-on-continuous-data